# Translation from Windows filename to Linux filename for WSL Ubuntu app

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

A general way to work with files in Windows is by dragging and dropping them into the application you want to use for viewing/working on that file (Notepad, Notepad++, Excel, etc.).

Since I have an Ubuntu app in WSL, I decided to do the same thing in order to search for something in `C:\Temp_Folder\Decompile\Decompile_Result.txt`, however Ubuntu doesn't understand such a location:

- I was expecting the app to translate the below, which didn't happen:

  ```bash
  "C:\Temp_Folder\Decompile\Decompile_Result.txt"

  to:

  "/mnt/c/Temp_Folder/Decompile/Decompile_Result.tx"
  ```

The Ubuntu app knows the relation between the Windows location [`C:`] and the Ubuntu location [`/mnt/c/`]:

```bash
WSL $ df -hk

  Filesystem  1K-blocks      Used  Available Use%  Mounted on
  rootfs      999036924 478061212  520975712  48%  /
  ...
  C:\         999036924 478061212  520975712  48%  /mnt/c
```

According to Windows' *Add and Remove* settings, the WSL version information is:

- Publisher : Canonical Group Limited 
   Version   : 2004.2022.1.0

Is there a version which covers this translation or is this planned in the future?

Comment: Are you using the "Windows Terminal" app, or the old built-in Windows console? Drag & drop is handled by the terminal itself, not actually by the program that runs inside.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm running Windows 10, Enterprise edition, version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1586).

Comment: I haven't used Win10 or WSL much but I have some doubts over whether that would work.. for example, while it's possible to drag a file onto the cmd prompt and get the path appear there.. It'd always be the same path. Whereas since you're talking about a thing different to the cmd prompt and within it, is something unlx/linux related and the unix/linux related thing could have a path anywhere for example suppose the unix/linux related thing was configured for files to be mounded somewhere other than /mnt  So windows would have to know.. That said....

Comment: funnily enough, I can drag a file onto a cygwin window and it translates the path. https://i.imgur.com/uasSer4.png so if that can be done then what you speak of should be able to be done

Answer (score 0):

This issue was addressed in the bug-report
[Drag & Drop from File Explorer produces incorrect file paths with WSL #331](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/331),
where the last comment from Feb 3, 2022, says:

> This issue was addressed in [#11625](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/11625), which has now been successfully released as `Windows Terminal Preview v1.13.10336.0`.

At this moment the current stable version is
[Windows Terminal v1.12.10393.0](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.12.10393.0).

You may either wait for `v1.13` to be released, or download and install
the preview release, which is at the moment
[Windows Terminal Preview v1.13.10395.0](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases).